# Executing a SSIS package from C# as proxy WITHOUT an agent job

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, proxy

I am facing a problem in a project I work on right now. I developed a small C# Tool which is used in order to maintain several tables etc. in SQL Server and which provides the possibility to call a SSIS package on a server and pass values from the DB tables to it.
However, in several environments I faced the problem, that SSIS has to be executed via a proxy user (which does already exists and which is used in several agent jobs.
Now, since I don't want to create a agent job for each and every package I want to execute, I tried to perform a `EXECUTE AS LOGIN...` before calling the package. Unfortunately I receive an error (something like `security can not be redirected. Please try to execute... in the same DB the EXEC AS LOGIN has been performed`.
So, is there ANY way to call a SSIS package and pass a proxy user name to it WITHOUT creating an agent job?

Thanks.

Comment: How are the packages deployed, using SSISDB? Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a parent package that calls a child package.  Then create an agent job that calls the parent package using the proxy.

The parent package reads a table and sets the name/location of the child package based on what's in the table, and then executes the child package.  You could optionally use a loop to execute multiple child packages, if there are multiple rows in the table.

The C# tool populates the table with the child package(s) you want to execute, and then starts the job.

I realize this doesn't answer the question of how to do it without creating a job at all, but I don't know any way to do that, and at least this way you only have to create one job for all your packages.